# Verify that the following Euler equation has a solution of y=Ct

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$t^{2}y'' - ty' + y = 0$$

Every time I try to solve this I can never come up with that solution. After I find that solution I know that I will need to use Reduction of Order to find the second solution. Please help!

Comment: Can you verify that $y = Ct$ is a solution? Also, try a power series solution.

Comment: All it's asking you to do is work out $y'$, $y''$ and plug them (and $y$) into the equation, when you do this you get the LHS being $0$ and so $y = Ct$ is a solution.

Comment: okay thank you everyone! I realized I was differentiating lamda like a variable so my first and second derivatives were wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(t) = y-t y'$. We have $g'(t) = -t y''$, hence the original ODE can be written as:
$$ -tg' + g = 0,\tag{1}$$
that is a separable ODE, leading to $g(t) = K t$. So we just have to solve:
$$ y - ty' = K t \tag{2}$$
and the solutions of $(2)$ (so all the solutions of the original ODE) are given by:
$$ y(t) = C t - K t \log t. \tag{3} $$